# How do I make an image shrink to fit inside a fixed position flex box modal

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, microsoft-edge

How do I make an image shrink to fit inside a fixed position flex box modal?

When trying the below the image overlaps the header/footer. It needs to work for images both tall, or wide, and in IE.

```css
.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-header {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.modal-body {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.modal-footer {
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        header
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x1200" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note this is a simple example, and I am really using a complicated SVG, not an image tag, so I can't use a background image.

Comment: `img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }`

Comment: @dgknca that distorts the image

Comment: `object-fit:cover;` ?

Comment: `max-width:100%;max-height:100%` ?

Comment: @dgknca that crops the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif that doesn't work Edge

Comment: `object-fit: contain` not sure about edge though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use good old `position: absolute` with max-width and `max-height`:

```css
/* for demonstration I have replaced all irrelavant styles with this */
.modal-body {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 10% auto 0;
  background: green;
}
/* parent must be positioned */
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
}
/* size and center */
.modal-body img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x1200" />
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working in my example cases, I'll try and use it in my real implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a reminder but by default images try to maintain their aspect ratios**, so simply setting a percentage width will allow an inlined image to grow to the proper height **OR** setting only the height to a percentage will maintain the width.

The key is to only set ONE dimension and let the browser figure out the rest.

This is especially true if you set the sizes **Inline** using the appropriate HTML structure.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x1200" width="100%" />
  </div>
```

Now you just set the max-width of the container with CSS and everything is happy. That should be true of any use of the `img` tag. Meaning if you use an SVG in the img src attribute you'll get it to function like an image. That said, I believe you lose SVG interactions if you do it that way.

---

So assuming you're going to actually drop the SVG into your code, you need to do a bit of work to the SVG.

Note how most SVG's have hard-coded heights and widths in the header Simply **removing the hard-coded height/width** "should" make the SVG scale correctly since the `view-box` keeps the proportions of the image.

```html
<svg width="299px" height="138px" viewBox="0 0 299 138" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="example">
            <rect id="Rectangle" fill="#D8D8D8" x="0" y="0" width="299" height="138"></rect>
            <circle id="Oval" fill="#46BEC6" cx="53" cy="50" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy" fill="#46BEC6" cx="105" cy="76" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy-2" fill="#46BEC6" cx="165" cy="95" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy-3" fill="#46BEC6" cx="217" cy="63" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy-4" fill="#46BEC6" cx="269" cy="32" r="26"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>



<svg viewBox="0 0 299 138" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="example">
            <rect id="Rectangle" fill="#D8D8D8" x="0" y="0" width="299" height="138"></rect>
            <circle id="Oval" fill="#46BEC6" cx="53" cy="50" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy" fill="#46BEC6" cx="105" cy="76" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy-2" fill="#46BEC6" cx="165" cy="95" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy-3" fill="#46BEC6" cx="217" cy="63" r="26"></circle>
            <circle id="Oval-Copy-4" fill="#46BEC6" cx="269" cy="32" r="26"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

If you don't know which one needs to be set (like in the case of a dynamic image) you'll need to measure it with javascript before applying the correct measurement. Something along these lines:

```
fixImage(){
  var img = findTheImageInTheDom;
  if (img.width > img.height){
    img.width = "100%";
  } else {
    img.height = "100%";
}
```

Comment: I might have to fallback to manually setting the size, but its a little more complicated than that. It would need compare the aspect ratio of the container to the image.